# Magento 1.7 : All PAge White after start Compilation

Tags: magento-1.7, compilation

After start Compilation i got white screen. IF i will disable compilation website working good.

I don't want to disable compilation so please don't suggest this type of answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are errors during the compiling stages. Your best best is to look at the logs or turn errors on to see if you can maybe fix the errors so you can compile appropriately.Maybe a new extension might be the issue, sometimes extension will have rewrites which conflict with one another, if so look at new additions made to the website and try disabling them before compiling.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.* , Compilation error occur due to third party plugin.

Need to check all third party module.
If you face blank page error after compilation....
add below code into index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

Add above code after `include Mage.php` .